# what is the implementation of foldGAll in wiki example

Tags: haskell

https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Monad.Reader/Issue5/Practical_Graph_Handling#foldG
i follow 1.5.2

after load trees.hs has error, just hope to run some examples in above link and export some graph jpeg or png file

```
Prelude> :l trees.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main ( trees.hs, interpreted )


trees.hs:39:22: parse error on input `='
Failed, modules loaded: none.



import Data.List
import Data.Array
--import Data.Graph 
import Control.Monad
import Math.Combinat
import Math.Core.Utils
import Math.Core.Field
import Math.Algebras.VectorSpace
import Math.Algebras.Structures
--import Math.CommutativeAlgebra.GroebnerBasis
--import Math.CommutativeAlgebra.Polynomial
--import Math.Algebras.Matrix
import System.IO
import qualified Data.Map as M


type Vertex = Int
type Table a = Array Vertex a
type Graph e = Table [(e, Vertex)]
type Bounds = (Vertex, Vertex)
type Edge e = (Vertex, e, Vertex)


type Labeling a = Vertex -> a
data LabGraph n e = LabGraph (Graph e) (Labeling n)


foldGAll :: (Eq r) => r -> (Vertex -> [(e, r)] -> r) -> Graph e -> Table r
foldGAll bot f gr = finalTbl
 where finalTbl = fixedPoint updateTbl initialTbl
          initialTbl = listArray bnds (replicate (rangeSize bnds) bot)

          fixedPoint f x = fp x
              where fp z = if z == z' then z else fp z'
                        where z' = f z
          updateTbl tbl = listArray bnds $ map recompute $ indices gr
              where recompute v = f v [(b, tbl!k) | (b, k) <- gr!v]
          bnds = bounds gr


foldG :: (Eq r) => r -> (Vertex -> [(e, r)] -> r) -> Graph e -> Vertex -> r
foldG i f g v = foldGAll i f g ! v


-- | Build a graph from a list of edges.
buildG :: Bounds -> [Edge e] -> Graph e
buildG bounds0 edges0 = accumArray (flip () [] bounds0 [(v, (l,w)) | (v,l,w) <- edges0]

-- | The graph obtained by reversing all edges.
transposeG :: Graph e -> Graph e
transposeG g = buildG (bounds g) (reverseE g)


edges :: Graph e -> [Edge e]
edges g = [ (v, l, w) | v <- indices g, (l, w) <- g!v ]

reverseE :: Graph e -> [Edge e]
reverseE g = [ (w, l, v) | (v, l, w) <- edges g ]


showGraphViz (LabGraph gr lab) = 
"digraph name {\n" ++
"rankdir=LR;\n" ++
(concatMap showNode $ indices gr) ++
(concatMap showEdge $ edges gr) ++
"}\n"
where showEdge (from, t, to) = show from ++ " -> " ++ show to ++
" [label = \"" ++ show t ++ "\"];\n"
showNode v = show v ++ " [label = " ++ (show $ lab v) ++ "];\n"



-- | Compute the distance to v for every vertex of gr.
distsTo :: Vertex -> Graph Float -> Table Float
distsTo v gr = foldGAll infinite distance gr 
where infinite = 10000000 -- well, you get the idea
distance v' neighbours 
| v == v' = 0
| otherwise = minimum [distV+arcWeight | (distV, arcWeight) <- neighbours]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have several problems with indentation in that source file. Your question is also not clear, so it's hard to help you, without more information on what you are trying to achieve.

In any case, the error message is quite clear: there is a problem where ghci is unable to parse an '=' sign in line 39, character 22. Keep in mind that indentation is part of the language and that many of these parsing errors are a consequence of improper indentation.

I hope this helps.